# How to create windows installer for php web application (install php, apache, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, windows-installer, customization

How to create windows installer for php web application? I want install PHP, MySQL, Apache with custom config and put my php file script in root of windows. As matter of fact I want to have a WAMP or XAMPP with custom configuration and my custom php file and my custom database in mysql.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

XAMPP is licensed as GPLv2, so you can package it along with your CMS to distribute. ([See the license info here.](https://www.apachefriends.org/about.html))

What you could do is use a pre-build install creator tool ([like Install Creator 2](http://www.clickteam.com/install-creator-2)) install XAMPP and then extract your CMS files as well. You could then have a short PHP setup script that sets up your databases and what not that you could program the installer to execute from the command line.

Comment: More such tools can be found at https://alternativeto.net/software/inno-setup/ (I haven't tried Inno Setup yet, but it is the most upvoted alternative to Install Creator at alternativeto.net and is FOSS – see license at https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/license.txt). Thanks for sharing, this was a nice starting point for to find some solution!